# How do I allow several Instagram authentications per user with OmniAuth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth, instagram

I need to allow users to authenticate with 3 Instagram accounts. I'm developing on Ruby On Rails and I'm using [Instagram OAuth](https://github.com/ropiku/omniauth-instagram).

In my `Devise` configuration I add `config.omniauth :instagram, ENV['INSTAGRAM_client'], ENV['INSTAGRAM_secret'], {:scope => 'basic'}`. This is only for one authentication. My question is how to setup 2 more different endpoints for authentication with different accounts so that I can handle them separately with this gem and how to access them?

Comment: Have you created a separate model to store authentications?

Comment: @papirtiger No, could you guide me how to do that? I will accept your answer. I need to get information from three Instagram applications for one user

Comment: @AigarsCibuļskis Please don't deface your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step to creating a multi-authentication (or multi provider) app is to separate your User model from authentications.

Make sure you read https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview before starting.

We want something like the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications
end

# Represents an OAuth authentication account 
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  alidates_uniqueness_of :uid, scope: :provider
end
```

This is based on a multi-provider setup - if you only intend to use Instagram you can omit the provider column. You can also name the model whatever you want - `OathAccount` or `InstagramAccount` or whatever you like.

We can generate the authentication model:

```
rails g authentication uid:string provider:string user:references
```

We also want to add a DB index speed up queries and ensure that we only have one authentication per twitter account. So let's edit the migration:

```
class CreateAuthentications < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :authentications do |t|
      # ...
    end
    # add this line
    add_index :authentications, [:provider, :uid], unique: true
  end
end
```

Now we need to handle the OAuth callback - which is shown after the provider dialog where they choose to approve or deny the app. Lets set up a route:

```
devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions], controllers: {
  omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks'
}
```

So now after the user signs in the will get routed to `/users/omniauth_callbacks/twitter`.

We then create a controller:

```
# app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def instagram
     # OmniAuth creates a normalized 
     # hash of the credentials and info supplied by the provider.
     @auth_params = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
     # @todo check if authentication exists
     # @todo find user for authentication
     # @todo create account for new users
     # @todo sign user in
  end
end
```

To handle all this logic we might want to call on a Service Object. These are just plain 
ruby objects which take an input and accomplish a task.

```
# app/services/authenticate_service
class AuthenticateService      
  # @param [Hash|OmniAuth::AuthHash] auth_hash
  # @param [User|nil] current_user
  # @return [Authentication]
  def call(auth_hash, current_user = nil)
    auth = Authentication.find_or_initialize_by(uid: auth_hash[:uid], provider: auth_hash[:provider])
    if !current_user || !auth.user 
      # You need to adapt this to the provider and your user model
      user = User.new(
        name: auth_hash[:info][:full_name]
      )
    end
    auth.update(user: current_user ? current_user : user)
  end
end
```

This makes it so much easier to test than if we had all the logic in our controller.
We can just inject whatever hash and use user object we want.

Just one little caveat - we need to tell rails to autoload our service

```
# config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'services', '{**}')]
```

Now lets call our service and sign the user in

```
# app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def instagram
    @auth = AuthenticateService.new.call(request.env['omniauth.auth'], current_user)
    @user = @auth.user
    if user_signed_in?    
      flash[:notice] = 'You have added a new authentication!'
      redirect_to :root
    else
      sign_in_and_redirect(:user, @user)
    end
  end
end
```

Suggested reading:

- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview
- https://github.com/intridea/omniauth#getting-started
- https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/
- https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Auth-Hash-Schema

Comment: This is a pretty advanced topic, you will need a basic knowledge about how Rails and OAuth work. I'm not going to handhold you if you are just starting out with rails.

Comment: Edit: removed a line faulty line which would try to assign the auth to the current user even if there was none.